# Java Class not Found Exception while doing Spark-submit Scala using sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

Here is my code that i wrote in scala

```
package normalisation

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import  org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem,Path}


object Seasonality {
 val amplitude_list_c1: Array[Nothing] = Array()
 val amplitude_list_c2: Array[Nothing] = Array()
 def main(args: Array[String]){
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Normalization")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
   val line = "MP"
   val ps = "Test"
   val location = "hdfs://ipaddress/user/hdfs/{0}/ps/{1}/FS/2018-10-17".format(line,ps)
   val files = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration ).listStatus(new Path(location))
   for (each <- files) {
     var ps_data = sqlContext.read.json(each)

   }
   println(ps_data.show())
 }
```

The error I received when compiled using sbt package is here[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frbxA.png)

Here is my build.sbt file

name := "OV"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1"

Answer (score 0):

in Spark Versions > 2 you should generally use `SparkSession`. 
See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

also then you should be able to do

```
val spark:SparkSession = ???
val location = "hdfs://ipaddress/user/hdfs/{0}/ps/{1}/FS/2018-10-17".format(line,ps)
spark.read.json(location)
```

to read all your json files in the directory.

Also I think you'd also get another compile error at

```
for (each <- files) {
  var ps_data = sqlContext.read.json(each)
}
println(ps_data.show())
```

for `ps_data` being out of scope.

If you need to use `SparkContext` for some reason it should indeed be in spark-core. Have you tried restarting your IDE, cleaned caches, etc?

EDIT: I just notices that `build.sbt` is probably not in the directory where you call `sbt package` from so sbt won't pick it up

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by ps_data being out of scope? I am not using any IDE here.just running it on terminal.Is not my sparkcontext in spark core itself?Sorry I am a newbie to spark

Comment: so `ps_data` is local to your for-loop and not visible to the outside.  But also it looks like you're calling `sbt package` from your source directory. your build.sbt needs to be in the directory where you call `sbt package` from